# Should I have flagged this question about financial data formats Unclear, Spam or both?

Tags: discussion, flags

Please have look with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633886/what-is-this-format-type

Which flag do I have to use, Spam or Unclear what you are asking?

And what happens if I make both flagged?

Comment: "and what happen if I make both flaged" Well one of them has been declined, since you actually went ahead and flagged *before* posting this question.

Comment: If you're going to just flag first and ask about it later, it's already too late. Next time you're not sure, **ask first instead**, so that the answers you receive aren't a waste of people's time. *What to do with this?* after you've already done something is meaningless.

Comment: Ironically, the question you have here isn't very much better than the one you link to. This title is even *worse* than that one, and the writing is just as atrocious, if not more. If this wasn't your own question I imagine you would have flagged this as spam too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for what constitutes spam are actually pretty specific. It's very low-quality, but not spam.

From [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work):

> A post should be marked as spam **ONLY** when it contains an [unsolicited advertisement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28electronic%29).
>
> It should **NOT** be marked as spam when:
>
> - The answer contains no useful information, such as an answer that says "I don't care about your problem". Flag an answer as 'not an answer' instead; if you find a weird non-question, then flag it 'for moderator attention' with a custom explanation.
> - It contains only gibberish, such as "fsdguejgkfdlk". Flag 'for moderator attention' with a custom explanation if it requires more detail. These flags are trivially handled by moderators and using spam/offensive for it poisons the data for anti-trolling and automated spam detection.

It deserves the downvotes it's getting for showing absolutely no research effort and being "not useful".

As for flagging, it's now closed, but I would've flagged it as off-topic. It's pretty clear what the OP is looking for, but it's not the kind of question that's on-topic on SO.

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 2):

It's not spam. Spam is an attempt to advertise something or to intentionally post noise or clutter, neither of which the post in question does.

It's a terrible question, but it's not spam. It should (and has been) closed as unclear, and is probably collecting deletion votes by now. It definitely does not meet the definition of spam.

It's important to know that spam flags have side effects other than the post being closed. A spam flag that is cast by enough users (3?) can result in a penalty of 100 reputation for the poster, and possible suspension of their account. If there is any question in your mind about whether the question is spam, you should either err on the side of caution and use a different close reason or ask here and let others decide.

Comment: Six users. There are no other repercussions, @Grant, at least not effected automatically along with deletion by spam flags.

Answer (score 1):

I'd flag it as "Unclear what you are asking". It doesn't look like spam: the Asker didn't include any links, phone numbers, or make any attempt to plug a product.

In fact, not naming the source of the data is the reason the question is unclear.