# Problem with closing discussions on Meta

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, meta

I'm fairly sure this will get closed, but here it goes...

I've been noticing an annoying trend here on Meta, it seems that unpopular opinions are being suppressed via closure.

Voting to close questions as dups of, at best, tangentially related questions and, my personal favorite, closing questions as "primarily opinion based" seems to be <strike>becoming the norm</strike> happening a little too often.

To be clear a lot of these closed posts aren't great, they're often unpopular for good reason, but shouldn't we be voicing disagreement with votes or, perhaps better, with answers rather than just shutting down the question?

Some examples. Note that many aren't good questions, and some perhaps should have been closed, but not for the reason used.

1. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298138/do-we-want-a-rainbow-hat
2. [Had the community responded in a negative way towards changing the site's logo temporarily, would Stack Overflow have changed it regardless?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297935/had-the-community-responded-in-a-negative-way-towards-changing-the-sites-logo-t)
3. [Question about programming, not a programming language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296494/question-about-programming-not-a-programming-language)
4. [What to do with this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295989/what-to-do-with-this)
5. [Do we allow religious invocations in questions/answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295810/do-we-allow-religious-invocations-in-questions-answers)
6. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298552/how-to-quote-part-of-the-question-a-subquestion-in-an-answer
7. [How can I make the best out of contributing to SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298479/how-can-i-make-the-best-out-of-contributing-to-so)

Please don't get overly hung up on the specific examples.

Comment: While I'm not sure I agree that this is a problem (ie, happening), I'm not voting to close this question :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Feel free to post an answer ;)

Comment: of course this isn't related to [some definitely-not-a-redditor](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5091533/dorrito) jumping in today to post a [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298766/839601) that purely incidentally reminds of [currently popular](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298693/839601) discussion at reddit

Comment: Only 1 out of the last 50 closed questions on Meta was closed as "primarily opinion based." This doesn't strike me as a widespread trend. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298698/1288

Comment: I've noticed this too. Closing as dupes wouldn't be such a problem if discussion shifted to the dupe, but usually the dupe close just shuts it down. Perhaps a question should be bumped to the first page when another question is closed as a dupe of it?

Comment: @gnat [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298762/should-so-have-a-wealth-tax-on-points?noredirect=1#comment217769_298762) was the latest in a string of these.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The specific reason is secondary to the apparent intent: "I don't like this... Have a close vote."

Comment: Yeah, but it's on you to show that that's actually happening, much less that it's "becoming the norm."

Comment: @apaul34208 I see. I think I will disappoint you by saying that if (when) it will get reopened, I plan to vote close as a dupe of [Advantage to Old Users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254964/839601)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Not sure how to do that without getting overly entangled in the specific questions used as examples.

Comment: @gnat That ones a bit better, at least it has a real answer, but the original reads more like problem statement with a specific feature request.

Comment: There is no general trend without some specific examples. If you can't show at least a few examples, there is no problem.

Comment: @BilltheLizard added a few examples, still hoping not to get hung up on the specific questions and take a look at the general issue.

Comment: @apaul34208 - One thing that does seem to be consistent across that set of questions is the users closing them. Sometimes these issues can be addressed with custom flags if you believe a user is inappropriately using their votes.

Comment: From my experience, it *does* occasionally happen, but rarely is a discussion shut down that doesn't just duplicate one that has been had previously. There are a couple of weird closings in that list of yours but I don't think unpopularity is the main factor there... more a strange desire to quickly close questions that didn't make it. I don't think it's a widespread problem in that it suppresses discussion

Comment: You were asking primarily about questions incorrectly marked as dupes of barely-related questions, but the examples you picked are more like vague/unclear/subjective questions. Can you give better examples to illustrate? also to establish how much a of a trend this is as you claim.

Answer (score 16):

**Should** we be doing this? Of course not.

That being said, I don't think this is actually happening. The two kinds of posts that this even *remotely* happens to are:

1. Posts that are beating a dead horse (downvote require comments, why we are all assholes, etc.) and so the answers still apply, even if the new post has a twist on the old idea. If such posts *addressed* the old ideas, and showed how they are better/fixed, then I doubt they would be closed as such.
2. Giant rants that don't promote discussion. I would close these as "Not constructive" except that isn't a reason, so I guess opinion-based would do. Certainly there are no facts being presented in such questions, just somebody's opinions.

But overall, there seem to be plenty of open, massively downvoted questions on Meta (reversal badge's anyone?) and those that do get closed are at least plausibly justified if not clear cut.

Comment: "Posts that are beating a dead horse" Sometimes a dead horse just needs one more good kick to get it in the grave. The size of the close vote queue was probably a good example of that, dozens of people beat that dead horse before something finally happened.

Comment: Not to say that all of those were good ideas, some were duplicates, some just rants, but if we close all questions having to do with a particular topic just because we're sick of it, we may miss a good solution at some point.

Comment: @apaul34208 No doubt, which is why a post that *shows* the dead horse, and explains why it is different is going to be received much better. Otherwise the answer is the same (ie, "We don't want anonymous downvotes"). I'm not saying all the duplicates are clear cut, just that they are justifiable enough to dissuade me from believing your premise that they are due to simple disagreement.

Comment: That's just one note though. Some rants, even though they are in fact rants, may contain something worth discussing and shouldn't necessarily be shut down for having an overly aggressive tone. Wouldn't editing be a better way to address some of these?

Comment: @apaul34208 Certainly. Editing takes more effort, and so I'm not necessarily *surprised* that it doesn't happen as much as it should. That said, I believe we would be better of if we (and I include myself here) were more trigger happy with the edit link than the close one. Many questions here and on the main site could be saved.

Comment: Rants are not a basis for discussion, period. You as the OP are the discussion starter and to some extent its leader. If you can't start it off in the best way possible, or go in kicking and punching, there is very little change anything productive will come out. You can try the clean-up, and I have on occasion, but more often than not it's wasted effort. So you're far better off stopping it right there. If that stops a discussion worth having, it's your [the OP's] own fault.

Comment: @Bart in my experience, "does not appear to seek input and discussion" is typically more (much more) appropriate close reason for rants than one asked about here ("opinion based")

Comment: Sure @gnat. I was merely referring to the comment and usefulness of editing a rant into shape.

Comment: @Bart on that I agree. I think it's more productive to [quickly cut the rant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/165773) (preferably with most appropriate close reason) and after that, safely edit it into shape (if possible) and reopen

Comment: *"Why we are all assholes"* cracked me up. I wonder what would be a good answer to that?

Comment: @kabanus Usually the answer is "We have rules and quality standards, the fact that you don't like that is not our problem".

Comment: *"But give me the codez or I flag!"*